# Multithreading accelerates CPU bound tasks despite of GIL

Tags: python, multithreading, gil

I recently learned about GIL in python.
I was doing some benchmarks and found out that multithreading actually does improve the performance. I compare elementwise NumPy operations that do not use any internal multithreading. In the first test, I call a function 32 times sequentially from a for loop. In the second case, I use multithreading. But if GIL was working, in the second case only 1 thread should be active at a time, so that the execution time should be approximately equal (even worse in the second case due to multithreading overhead). This is not what I observed.

```
import os
import threading
import numpy as np, time

def elemntwiseoperations(a,b):
    np.exp(a)+np.sin(b)
        
N=1024
a=np.random.rand(N,N)
b=np.random.rand(N,N)


NoTasks=32

start_time = time.time()
for i in range(NoTasks):
    elemntwiseoperations(a,b)
print("Execution time for {} tasks: {} seconds, {} seconds per task".format(NoTasks,time.time() - start_time,(time.time() - start_time)/NoTasks))

threads=[]
start_time = time.time()
for i in range(NoTasks):
    x = threading.Thread(target=elemntwiseoperations,name=''.format(i),args=(a,b))
    x.start()
    threads.append(x)
    
for process in threads:
    process.join()

print("Execution time for {} tasks: {} seconds, {} seconds per task".format(NoTasks,time.time() - start_time,(time.time() - start_time)/NoTasks))
```

Output:

```
Execution time for 32 tasks: 0.5654711723327637 seconds, 0.01767103374004364 seconds per task
Execution time for 32 tasks: 0.17153215408325195 seconds, 0.005360409617424011 seconds per task
```

P.S. MAC os, python 3.7.6, Cpython implementation.

Comment: Keep in mind that the GIL only applies to the interpretation of Python bytecodes.  Code that was implemented in C can (optionally) run without the GIL locked, and it's likely that NumPy's more CPU-intensive operations are implemented in C and thus are able to run in parallel with each other.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner thanks for the hint. I've posted the answer the way I understand it, but I don't know how to check if what I understand is actually true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, my current best guess is the following:
In the first case, one thread starts C routines sequentially. It waits for each to finish before starting the new one. Since I only use elementwise operation that are not parallelized in numpy, only one thread is invloved in the whole process.

In the second case, I call for 32 virtual threads, each is affected by the GIL. The first thread starts up C routine and gives GIL control to the second thread, then the second thread starts C routine and gives control to the third thread, and so on. Even though C routines are called not at the same time, they all execute concurtently, as C is not affected by GIL.

I don't know how to actually check it, but this is how I understand it after reading a couple of python blogs about GIL.

Comment: You can check if your code is running on one or multiple cores. Depending on your OS, you can use the corresponding tool that lets you see the CPU usage of different processes (e.g. Activity Monitor on MacOS). You can also use the top command in bash to see the real-time CPU usage of your processes. When I check your code like this, I can see that the sequential part never crosses 100% (1 core), while the multithreaded part goes up to 350% (3.5 cores). I have 4 (logical) cores.

Comment: Yeah, so it looks like in the multi-threading case it runs in parallel because of asynchronous execution of Python code and subordinate C routines. In Python, 1 thread is active at a time. However, when the threads execute C code they are not bound by GIL